# Get a pdf using a HttpWebRequest GET call in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get the report pdf from https://www.creditsafe.com/ using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse.

In the documentation from credit safe it says the I need to set the Content-Type of the request to be "application/pdf".

Everything works fine when using postman, but when I try to do it in c# it always returns a response of type "application/json"

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest_CompanyCreditReport_PDF = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlraport);
httpWebRequest_CompanyCreditReport_PDF.Method = "GET";
httpWebRequest_CompanyCreditReport_PDF.Headers["Authorization"] = token;
httpWebRequest_CompanyCreditReport_PDF.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf";

HttpWebResponse httpResponse_CompanyCreditReport_PDF = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest_CompanyCreditReport_PDF.GetResponse();
```

Can someone point what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Take a look at the raw message in Postman.  I suspect you aren't sending all the headers that postman is doing.

Comment: Postman can even generate you the C# code as a reference implementation

Comment: `Content-Type` is for sending data. It's not needed for `GET`. To specify expected content type to be received use `Accept` header, but in your case is must work without it. Btw, it's recommended to use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) instead of ancient `HttpWebRequest`, especially in .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @tawman for guiding me to use Postman's code generator, I ended up using the c# RestSharp code which works great.